# ReplyTo property missing in SOAPHeader

Tags: wso2, bpel, asynccallback, ws-addressing

I have created a WS-BPEL workflow that would call an asynchronous web service and wait for a callback response. The carbon application is successfully deployed into BPS as well.

**Details on my external Asynchronous web service**
 1. It requires basic authentication over http.
 2. It requires the soap header to be available in the soap envelope.
 3. It would process the request and send a callback to the **ReplyTo** address it receives in the soap header and use the **MessageID** to correlate the callback.

My **deploy.xml** file for the BPEL process looks like this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<deploy xmlns="http://www.apache.org/ode/schemas/dd/2007/03" 
    xmlns:callback.integration.service="http://callback.integration.service/"
    xmlns:epr="http://wso2.org/bps/bpel/endpoint/config" 
    xmlns:sample="http://wso2.org/bps/sample" 
    xmlns:ws.integration.service="http://ws.integration.service/">
   <process name="sample:Test">
      <active>true</active>
      <retired>false</retired>
      <process-events generate="all"/>
      <provide partnerLink="client">
         <service name="sample:Test" port="TestPort"/>
      </provide>
      <provide partnerLink="IntegrationService">
         <service name="callback.integration.service:IntegrationCallback" port="IntegrationResponsePort"/>
      </provide>
      <invoke partnerLink="IntegrationService">
         <service name="ws.integration.service:IntegrationService" port="IntegrationRequestPort">
            <epr:endpoint endpointReference="IntegrationService.epr"/>
         </service>
      </invoke>
   </process>
</deploy>
```

The **IntegrationService.epr** file looks like this ...

```
<wsa:EndpointReference
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com uep_schema.xsd"
        xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
        xmlns:wsdl11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
   <wsa:Address>http://http://server:8080/integration/IntegrationService</wsa:Address>
   <wsa:Metadata>
      <id>SInvokeEPR</id>
      <qos>
         <enableAddressing />
      </qos>
      <transport type="http">
         <authorization-username>username</authorization-username>
         <authorization-password>password</authorization-password>
      </transport>
   </wsa:Metadata>
</wsa:EndpointReference>
```

Now when I test the bpel process from carbon service management console, I do get a request to my asynchronous web service. However the soap envelope looks as followed and it is missing a proper **ReplyTo** address to send the callback.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:To>http://server:8080/integration/IntegrationService</wsa:To>
        <wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/none</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:91ac4ebd-b100-440e-a01d-c4a5c0d8a56f</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:Action>http://ws.integration.service/IntegrationRequestPortType/createTask</wsa:Action>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>  
       ...
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now my need is to reply to this request with a callback. The callback soap envelope would contain this **MessageID** so that the callback correlates with the correct process instance.

How do you get the proper **ReplyTo** address appended to the soap header?

Comment: I am using BPS version  3.0.0 and using the latest WSO2 Developer Studio version as well. I've done the BPEL process acording to the samples provided [Here by Azeez](http://blog.afkham.org/2012/05/ws-bpel-spec-sample-using-wso2-bps.html)

Comment: I got correlation to work with WS-BPEL correlation sets. Somehow ws-Addressing based correlation is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume correctly you use the WSO2 BPS (or something with Apache ODE), you can use this copy in an assign to set the Header by hand. (http://ode.apache.org/extensions/headers-handling.html)

```
<bpel:copy>
  <bpel:from>
   <bpel:literal>
     <wsa:ReplyTo xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Address>http://localhost:9763/services/SIServerCallback</Address>
     </wsa:ReplyTo>
   </bpel:literal>
 </bpel:from>
 <bpel:to variable="ServiceInvokerIARequest" header="ReplyTo">
 </bpel:to>
</bpel:copy>
```